# Scanning VirtualBox XP Guest from ubuntu Host

Tags: virtualbox, anti-virus

I run Windows XP for occasional .Net dev and other downloads that are Win specific in VirtualBox 4.1 on top of a Ubuntu 11.04 host. I dont want to burden the guest with active Anti Virus. Is there any effective solutions for scanning from the host nightly, i.e. reading the vdmk presuming the guest file system is unencrypted? Is this as effective? Parts of me things probably more effective than in-guest scanning due no rootkits being able to alter scanning behavior?

Answer (score 0):

McAfee does an offline virtual disk scanner - [here](http://www.mcafee.com/uk/products/virusscan-enterprise-for-offline-virtual-images.aspx) - never used it, but clearly the technology is 'possible'.  Whether there are any free options, I'm not sure either.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with a Virus Scanner that runs on you Linux host , which depends on the format of your VirtualBox's disk , which format did you use ? You specified 'vdmk' here , is that a typo ?

AFAIK , only VMDK can be mounted